# Pandas dataframe two column condition and replace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame in that I want to put filter or condition for particularly for two column want change the values if values not pass the threshold change to zero, I know that I can do it with convert to separate dataframe do the filter and merge is there any other efficient way I can do, please suggest me.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1"],
                  "Amount": [10.0, 1.0, 8.0, 2, 7.5, 8.0],
                  "Amount2": [1, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 0, 8.0]})
```

output i want >2 threshold

```
User  Amount  Amount2

user1    10.0      0.0
user2     0.0      5.0
user2     8.0      8.0
user3     0.0     10.5
user2     7.5      0.0
user1     8.0      8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `clip` value below `2` to `2` then replace `2` to `0`

```py
df[['Amount', 'Amount2']] = df[['Amount', 'Amount2']].clip(lower=2).replace(2, 0)
```

```
print(df)

    User  Amount  Amount2
0  user1    10.0      0.0
1  user2     0.0      5.0
2  user2     8.0      8.0
3  user3     0.0     10.5
4  user2     7.5      0.0
5  user1     8.0      8.0
```

Comment: interesting, but this requires two passes and doesn't not enable to set a strict "lower than" threshold ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to handle all desired columns at once:

```
# select desired columns (here based on name)
cols = df.filter(like='Amount').columns
# it's also possible to manually set them
# cols = ['Amount', 'Amount2']

df[cols] = np.where(df[cols].le(2), 0, df[cols])  # or .lt(2) for <
```

updated `df`:

```
    User  Amount  Amount2
0  user1    10.0      0.0
1  user2     0.0      5.0
2  user2     8.0      8.0
3  user3     0.0     10.5
4  user2     7.5      0.0
5  user1     8.0      8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
threshold = 2
df.loc[(df['Amount'] < threshold),'Amount'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Amount2'] < threshold),'Amount2'] = 0
```

Comment: It would be great if you had added some explanation in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ill keep that in mind when answering in future

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where:

```
import numpy as np
df['Amount'] = np.where(df['Amount'] < 2,0, df['Amount'])
df['Amount2'] = np.where(df['Amount2'] < 2,0, df['Amount2'])
```

Or if you have only these columns in your dataframe:

```
df = df.where(df < 2, 0)
```